# How can I change link target to _blank in a external JS file located in other site? It's possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is working fine, but I want to have the link open in a new window

Here is my code:

```
HdiBanner = new function() {
    function d(b) {
        var d = document.getElementById(a);
        d.innerHTML = "<img src='" + img + "'>", d.onclick = function() {
            document.location.href = c + "?h=" + encodeURIComponent(broker)
        }, d.style.cursor = "pointer"
    }
    var a = "hdi_banner",
        b = "https://www.hdi.com.br/2010/imagens/hdi_gerling_logo.gif",
        c = "https://www.hdi.com.br/col/auth";
    this.init = function() {
        document.write("<div id='" + a + "'></div>"), d();
        var b = document.getElementById("no_script");
        b && (b.style.display = "none")
    }
}, HdiBanner.init()
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.open()`?

Comment: that is some funky code there!! I would've said add target attribute to the anchor with value `_blank` ... but I can't even tell what your code does!

Comment: This code cannot be executed. Variable `img` and `broker` are not defined.

Comment: Okay, I must be confusing you. The insurance company sends a code that calls the JS file to add a image with a link that leads to a page of calculations, this link being generated through a type of totem that defines who is making the sale. The JS file is located on the company website. Here is the code image that they send us and that defines the variables "img" and "broker" (totem).

![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/pceef6c)